# Can an IP address be incorrect?

Tags: gmail, google-search, geolocation, ip-addresses

Today while doing a Google search, I noticed at the bottom of the search results page a city and state that is not mine and the phrase "From your Internet address." I don't know if this has always appeared or I just never noticed.

Later as I was using Gmail and clicked on Details, the same city and state appeared. This city and state have never shown up here before.

The IP address also was different. Usually my IP address is X6.XXX.XX.XX but in this case it was X4.XX.X.X.

Is this something I should worry about?

Comment: Did you check the Google support articles? [Your location](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/179386?hl=en-AU) and [About IP address](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1696588)

Answer (score 1):

> Can an IP address be incorrect?

For all practical purposes, No.

> Is this something I should worry about?

Again, No. It is effectively the location of a node that handles your traffic, and though probably 'local' this can change.